# Allow USB debug pop-up not showing while installing CyanogenMod on Galaxy S3 i9300

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-3

I'm trying to install CyanogenMod on my Samsung Galaxy S3 (i9300, international). Had no problems, until I had to switch to the pc installer.

I'm stuck on the screenshot underneath:

[image: Allow USB debugging]

I have enabled USB debugging on my device (since the day I got it), did all the stuff asked up until now, but I can't continue here. It doesn't show any pop-up on the device, USB debugging is enabled.

Can anybody help me?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to my problem was simply revoking all authorisations granted to computers already. After rebooting both my Galaxy S3 and my laptop, the pop-up appeared again and I could continue the installation of CyanogenMod, which has now succesfully completed.

Answer (score 2):

I also got the same issue in my lenovo mobile. Initially I thought the issue is with my mobile.

But actually the issue is the `adb` don't have enough permission to read the `rsa key` to communicate with the device. When we run `adb server` it'll create a folder named `.android`(Linux - `/home/--username--/.android`, Windows - `C:/Users/--username--/.android`) in the home directory of the current user which contains the `adb rsa key` files used to communicate between the devices. When I check the folder is assigned with `root` permission(I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and I don't know how its assigned).

So I deleted the folder using below command. Use the particular method to delete the folder based on your operating system. Below I mentioned for linux.

> sudo rm -rf .android

Then restarted the `adb server` using below command.

> adb start-server

Now It created the `.android` folder with the current user permission. Once done this I got the `Allow USB debugging` dialog.

Hope it help someone.